# What does DmR and DmT means in Terms of SEO?

Tags: seo

Just read it on SEOMoz website. What is DmR and Dmt Abbreviated for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's based on the linkscape algorithm:

- mR = mozRank
- mT = mozTrust
- DmR = Domain mozRank
- DmT = Domain mozTrust